# img on error event for dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the `src`s of all invalid images on my website.

There is a lot of dynamic content on my site, so I came up with this simple code:

```
$(document).on("error", "img", function (e) {
    var $element = $(e.currentTarget);
    $element.attr("src", "images/oops.png");
});
```

It does not get called though. This same method works for click events (and many other types of events).

Comment: It seems okay.. How do you make sure it doesn't get called? Try using`alert` or `console.log` to double-check

Comment: @Bla... I have doubled checked. Not getting called :|

Answer (score 0):

this should work (it work for me ;D)

```
jQuery("<img />")
        .on('load', function() {
           //this are correct
        })
        .on('error', function() {
           //here the error
        })
        .attr("src", urlToComprobate);
```

you can try it into jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87wkf0cc/

when you create a DOM image (with `jQuery("<img />")`) are empty and when you force the load (with `attr`) can check if exist or not the url